# Traefik - short names of docker generated frontends

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, traefik

Is there any way to customize/short the names of the frontend, which are automatically created by docker with labels. For example I have this long name:
`frontend-Host-dashboard-test-local-www-dashboard-test-local-0`

For backends we can use this label:
`"traefik.backend=traefik"`

[Example of a long frontend and short backend name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO65L.png)

File generated Frontends and Backends are absolute shorten, they also have not the Frontend/Backend prefix.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: Not really. I think it is not possible because of the answer of this issue:
https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4619